# HTML correctly calling Apps Script function, but not receiving any data

Tags: javascript, html, google-sheets, google-apps-script

I am working on having a side bar open on a spreadsheet that shows case notes that are filtered by case numbers. I have the side bar correctly opening with a search box. I am searching for a known case number (its sample data with only 5 rows), and the HTML code is properly calling my function 'getInfoById()'. The execution log in the Apps Script editor shows the correct case number when logged, shows all the values from the sheet when values is logged, and shows the correct matchedRows. However, in the console log for the HTML, it shows that the data received in null

I have reworded this code in multiple ways. I have tried to call all data without filtering. I have run test arguments manually through the adds script, and have previously had code to test to see if I could write code through HTML thats passed through Apps Script and added to the Google Sheet, and was successfully able to do so. This latest re-iteration is code that was tweaked from a coworker using it on a different test data set. I am wondering if there is a setting that needs to be adjusted. Any help would be greatly appreciated. And forgive me if I didn't structure any info correctly in this question. This is the first time I have posted here.

Html Code Java Script

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <label for="idInput">ID:</label>
      <input type="number" id="idInput">
      <button onclick="getInfo()">Search</button>
    </div>
    <div id="info"></div>
    <script>
  function getInfo() {
    const searchId = document.getElementById('idInput').value;
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(data) {
      console.log('Data received:', data); // Debugging: Log the received data
      const infoDiv = document.getElementById('info');
      infoDiv.innerHTML = ''; // Clear existing content
      //if statement will be updated once the data is communicated properly
      if (data && data.length > 0) { // Ensure data is not null or empty
        data.forEach(function(row, index) {
          const recordHtml = `School: ${row[0]}<br>Name: ${row[1]}<br>ID: ${row[2]}<br><button onclick="editRecord(${index}, '${row[2]}')">Edit</button><br><br>`;
          infoDiv.innerHTML += recordHtml;
        });
      } else {
        infoDiv.innerHTML = 'No matching records found.';
      }
    }).withFailureHandler(function(error) { // Handle failure case
      console.error('Error:', error); // Log any errors
      const infoDiv = document.getElementById('info');
      infoDiv.innerHTML = 'Error occurred while retrieving data.';
    }).getInfoById(searchId); // Call the getInfoById function with the searchId
  }


 function editRecord(index, id) {
    const columnChoice = window.prompt("Choose column to edit (1 for School, 2 for Name, 3 for ID):");
    let newValue = window.prompt("Enter new value:");
    
    // Validate input
    if (!newValue || !columnChoice || isNaN(columnChoice) || columnChoice < 1 || columnChoice > 3) {
      alert("Invalid input. Please try again.");
      return;
    }
    
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function() {
      // Feedback to user
      alert("Record updated successfully.");
      getInfo(); // Refresh the listing to show updated data
    }).updateRecordById(id, columnChoice, newValue);
  }
</script>

  </body>
</html>
```

Apps Script Code

```
function getInfoById(searchId) {
  Logger.log(searchId)
  const sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName('Sheet1');
  const range = sheet.getDataRange();
  const values = range.getValues();
  Logger.log(values)
  const matchedRows = [];
  for (let i = 1; i < values.length; i++) {
    if (values[i][0].toString() === String(searchId)) {
      matchedRows.push([values[i][0], values[i][1], values[i][5]]);
    }
  }
  Logger.log(matchedRows)
  return matchedRows; // Return all matched rows
}
```

I have reworded this code in multiple ways. I have tried to call all data without filtering. I have run test arguments manually through the adds script, and have previously had code to test to see if I could write code through HTML thats passed through Apps Script and added to the Google Sheet, and was successfully able to do so. This latest re-iteration is code that was tweaked from a coworker using it on a different test data set. I am wondering if there is a setting that needs to be adjusted. Any help would be greatly appreciated. And forgive me if I didn't structure any info correctly in this question. This is the first time I have posted here.

Comment: [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example): "If a web page problem requires HTML, some styles, and some JavaScript, include code for all three." 
file.html?

Comment: Thanks @BorisBaublys. I have updated the above HTML code, to be the full html code called pages.html, instead of just a snippet

Comment: I checked and it works for me now. But where is the code for the function updateRecordById(id, columnChoice, newValue)?

Comment: Please note that if any of the values in the array `matchedRows` are Dates you can not transmit Dates from server to client.  See [google.script.run](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/html/reference/run)

Comment: @BorisBaublys I didn't include that script since it did not have to do with the issue that I was encountering.

Comment: @TheWizEd, thank you. The date was the issue with the script. I will need to think of a work around for this

Comment: You simply have to pass the date as a string and then translate back to date on the client side.